# sql server select query a bit complex

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a `item_prices` table with prices. Those prices vary at any time.

I want to display all items where date is highest

**ITEM_prices**

```
id | Items_name | item_price | item_date
------------------------------------------
1        A          10         2012-01-01
2        B          15         2012-01-01
3        B          16         2013-01-01
4        C          50         2013-01-01
5        A          20         2013-01-01
```

I want to display ABC items once each with highest date like as below

```
id | Items_name | item_price | item_date
-------------------------------------------
3        B          16         2013-01-01
4        C          50         2013-01-01
5        A          20         2013-01-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you can use native functions then why to go for any window function or CTE.

```
    SELECT t1.*
    FROM ITEM_prices t1
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT Items_name,MAX(item_date) AS MaxItemDate
        FROM ITEM_prices
        GROUP BY Items_name
    )t2
        ON t1.Items_name=t2.Items_name AND t1.item_date=t2.MaxItemDate
```

Comment: this one worked for me but after replacing last t2.item_date with t2.MaxItemDate    thankyou

Comment: yes my bad, query was not tested on dummy schema. i have corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use a CTE (Common Table Expression) if you're on SQL Server **2005 and newer** (you aren't specific enough in that regard).

With this CTE, you can partition your data by some criteria - i.e. your `Items_name` - and have SQL Server number all your rows starting at 1 for each of those "partitions", ordered by some criteria.

So try something like this:

```
;WITH NewestItem AS
(
   SELECT 
       id, Items_name, item_price, item_date,
       RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Items_name ORDER BY item_date DESC) 
   FROM 
       dbo.ITEM_Prices
)
SELECT 
   id, Items_name, item_price, item_date
FROM 
   NewestItem
WHERE
   RowNum = 1
```

Here, I am selecting only the "first" entry for each "partition" (i.e. for each `Items_Name`) - ordered by the `item_date` in descending order (newest date gets RowNum = 1).

Does that approach what you're looking for??

Comment: please add comma to query before RowNum

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use window functions to find the maximum date for each item:

```
select id, Items_name, item_price, item_date
from (select ip.*,
             max(item_date) over (partition by items_name) as max_item_date
      from item_prices
     ) ip
where item_date = max_item_date;
```

Comment: Don't you need to join on items_name too?

Comment: this does not work, just tested. can you check it before posting?

Answer (score 0):

This will select all rows with the max date.

```
SELECT * 
FROM item_prices
WHERE item_date = (SELECT max(item_date) FROM item_prices)
ORDER BY ID
```

This will select all rows for each item with the max date for that item.

```
select id, Items_name, item_price, item_date
from (select items_name, max(item_date) max_item_date
      from item_prices
      group by items_name
     ) ip
where item_date = max_item_date and items_name = ip.items_name
```